# Typescript get constant from other file by name

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 2 files

###### contants-ltr.ts

```
export const MY_CONST_1_NAME = "foo";
export const MY_CONST_2_NAME = "bar";
export const MY_CONST_3_NAME = "too";
export const MY_CONST_4_NAME = "far";
```

###### contants-rtl.ts

```
export const MY_CONST_1_NAME = "oof";
export const MY_CONST_2_NAME = "rab";
export const MY_CONST_3_NAME = "oot";
export const MY_CONST_4_NAME = "raf";
```

Can I do something like this

```
import * as LTR from './contants-ltr';
import * as RTL from './contants-rtl';

class Foo {
    
    public isRTL:boolean = false;
    public reference:1|2|3|4 = 1;

    public make():string {
        let origin = this.isRTL ? RTL:LTR;
        return origin[`MY_CONST_${this.reference}_NAME`];
    }
}
```

My actual use case is more complex but should simplify the problem. This also can be useful when working with locales for example. Note, names are checked so constants do exist, also I know that, for few constants, I can use switch case and call `return RTL.MY_CONST_1_NAME` but this is not the case

Comment: @MikeS. Thanks :) one last thing, I'm using angular with strict mode, do you have any tip for the this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type ... can't be used to index type 'typeof ` file1, file2...etc

Comment: Just remembered I can use `keyof typeof origin`, I will leave the comment in case someone faces the same :)

Comment: I'm just going to point out that with your code, there is no error: https://tsplay.dev/N55g0N